# Extract specific word from a string

Tags: php, string, preg-match

It might seem easy to do but I have trouble extracting this string. I have a string that has `@` tags in it and I'm trying to pull the tags `maps/place/Residences+Jardins+de+Majorelle/@33.536759,-7.613825,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m2!3m1!1s0xda62d6053931323:0x2f978f4d1aabb1aa`

And here is what I want to extract `33.536759,-7.613825,17z` :

```
$var = preg_match_all("/@(\w*)/",$path,$query);
```

Any way I can do this? Much appreciated.

Comment: Is the string always going to be formatted exactly the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your regex to this one:  `/@([\w\d\.\,-]*)/`.

Answer (score 2):

This will return the string beginning with @.

```
$string = 'maps/place/Residences+Jardins+de+Majorelle/@33.536759,-7.613825,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m2!3m1!1s0xda62d6053931323:0x2f978f4d1aabb1aa';
$string = explode('/',$string);
//$coordinates = substr($string[3], 1);
//print_r($coordinates);

foreach ($string as $substring) {
  if (substr( $substring, 0, 1 ) === "@") {
    $coordinates = $substring;
  }
}
echo $coordinates;
```

Comment: I want to extract word that begins with `@`

Answer (score 2):

A regex would do.

```
   /@(-*\d+\.\d+),(-*\d\.\d+,\d+z*)/
```

Answer (score 2):

If there is only one @ and the string ends with / you can use the following code:

```
//String
$string = 'maps/place/Residences+Jardins+de+Majorelle/@33.536759,-7.613825,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m2!3m1!1s0xda62d6053931323:0x2f978f4d1aabb1aa';

//Save string after the first @
$coordinates = strstr($string, '@');

//Remove @
$coordinates = str_replace('@', '', $coordinates);

//Separate string on every /
$coordinates = explode('/', $coordinates );

//Save first part
$coordinates = $coordinates[0];

//Do what you want
echo $coordinates;
```

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally added a third parameter to strstr. Now it works correctly.

Answer (score 2):

This is working for me:

```
$path = "maps/place/Residences+Jardins+de+Majorelle/@33.536759,-7.613825,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m2!3m1!1s0xda62d6053931323:0x2f978f4d1aabb1aa";
$var = preg_match_all("/@([^\/]+)/",$path,$query);
print $query[1][0];
```

Answer (score 1):

do like this

```
$re = '/@((.*?),-(.*?),)/mi'; 
$str = 'maps/place/Residences+Jardins+de+Majorelle/@33.536759,-7.613825,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m2!3m1!1s0xda62d6053931323:0x2f978f4d1aabb1aa'; 

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);

echo $matches[2][0].'<br>';
echo $matches[3][0];
```

***output***

```
33.536759
7.613825
```